# jQuery UI datepicker doesn't open after click on the map

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, yandex-api

I use jQuery UI datepicker and yandex map.

The ordinary work of datepicker is:
click on datepicker - open calendar popup
click around datepicker - hide calendar popup

But yet I use yandex map and when you click on the map and then click on datepicker - calendar popup can't be opened.

What is the source of problem can be? How to fix it?

Comment: use "inspect element" in your browser to see what class the popup has when it works correctly, now add `.myClass{ z-index:1000 !important;}`  somewhere in your CSS  ( where "myClass" is the class of your calendar popup) and see if that fixes it. I had a similar problem when using a popup calendar inside of a modal, the popup was appearing but it was appearing behind the modal....might be the same sort of thing here

Comment: The source of the problem is that when you click on the map, then datepicker doesn't lose focus, I think.

Comment: could you please add some code?